# How to specify programming language for 'Fastfile' in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, fastlane

I use Fastlane in my Android Project. And when I open 'fastlfile' file, Android Studio doesn't recognize this file as ruby code. And the code is not colorful. How can I specify programming language for the file?

Comment: I found some solution: add extension "rb"  (f.e. "fastlane.rb") to the file and Android Studio recognize the file properly. But I am not sure that it's a correct way, and it will not change anything for fastlane system.

Comment: The problem with @Ponomarenko Oleh solution is that when running the fastlane command afterwards it's possible that you will have to implicitly specify the Fastfile filename, since by default, fastlane will search for a `Fastfile` named file, not `Fastfile.rb` file.

In any case it's not a bad solution, but you would want to take this into account.

Answer (score 2):

As of Android Studio Bumblebee, the solution below is obsolete as Ruby syntax highlighting was added for `Fastfile` (and many other *extensionless* files).

I'll keep the old solution here, for reference.

---

I discovered that Android Studio Arctic Fox (latest at time of writing) already includes the ruby syntax from TextMate. All that was needed was to associate `Fastfile` with it.

To do it, I edited the embedded bundle configuration file (this is the path on MacOS, adapt for other platforms):

`"/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles/ruby/package.json"`

In the file, I added `Fastfile` to the list of files:

```
            ...
            "filenames": [ "rakefile", "gemfile", "guardfile", "podfile", "capfile", "Vagrantfile", ".simplecov", "Fastfile" ],
            ...
```

I didn't search much, but couldn't find a way of doing it in the preferences.

Comment: worked for me on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3

Comment: ah, problem is it prevents update patches from working 

Comment: I had the same problem with updates. I could make the update work by reverting the file to the original state (just remove the entry for Fastfile and the comma). Now I changed the file again, but kept the original one handy for the next update...

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with file types that are not recognized by Android studio (for example, if it's a proprietary file type developed in-house), or if you need to code in an unsupported language, you can create a custom file type.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/creating-and-registering-file-types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jetbrain's Toolbox to manager your Android Studio's install, you'll find the file here.

**⚠️** The version may change depending on your version of Android Studio for me it's : 221.6008.13.2211.9619390

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/221.6008.13.2211.9619390/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles/ruby/package.json
```